# Clearing FlipTileData BackBackgroundImage

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8

I have a periodic task that updates my live tile.  Basically it looks like this:

```
    var tileData = new FlipTileData()
    {
        BackgroundImage = mediumFrontUrl,
        BackBackgroundImage = mediumBackUrl,
        WideBackgroundImage = wideFrontUrl,
        WideBackBackgroundImage = wideBackUrl
    };

    ShellTile primaryTile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.First();
    if (primaryTile != null)
    {
        primaryTile.Update(tileData);
    }
```

There are certain occasions where I would like to not display the BackBackgroundImage and WideBackBackgroundImage.  How do I clear the values?  Simply setting things to `null` doesn't work (it just keeps what was there previously).  According to the docs if I use XAML to create the live tile I can set `Action="Clear"`.  How do I set that in code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can clear the property for each Tile property.

For BackBackgroundImaga it's Empty URI:
BackBackgroundImage = new Uri("", UriKind.Relative)

More info on msdn page Tiles Overview for Windows Phone:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202948%28v=vs.92%29.aspx

Hope this help
Best regards

Answer (score 0):

And Zik

Just one trick.
Playing with WideBackContent and putting my own image (I have a lot of more possibilities with this apporach) I have problem with resetting WideBackContent. The thing that help me is not WideBackContent ="", then WideBackContent = " "
So, one empty space solved my problem. 
Best regards

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind.  In my current project I only use images on the tiles but you never know about future projects.